# What is the Divergence of a Spherically Symmetric Vector Fields?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, vector-analysis, applications, divergence-operator

> A vector field is spherically symmetric about the origin if, on every sphere centered at the
> origin, it has constant magnitude and points either away from or toward the origin. A vector
> field that is spherically symmetric about the origin can be written in terms of the spherical
> coordinate $F = f(\rho)e_\rho$ where $f$ is a function of the distance $ρ$ from the origin,
> $f(0) = 0$, and $e_ρ$ is a unit vector pointing away from the origin.
>
> Show that $\operatorname{div} F = \frac 1 {\rho^2} \frac{d(\rho^2f(\rho))}{d \rho}
> , ρ \neq 0.$
>
> Source: *Hughes-Hallet*, freely available [here (project #2)](https://bcs.wiley.com/he-bcs/Books?action=mininav&bcsId=10457&itemId=1119320496&assetId=425049&resourceId=41665&newwindow=true).

My work is below.  I request verification or feedback.

**Note:** This problem is trivial to solve using the Divergence Theorem in Spherical Coordinates.  But that has not yet been taught in the book; the point of this problem is to **derive** Divergence Theorem in Spherical Coordinates, or at least as much as you need to solve the problem.

---

Consider the point $v_0$ on the $x$ axis such that $$\begin{align*}v_0 &= \langle \rho_0, 0, 0 \rangle\\
f_0 &= f(\rho_0)\\
F(v_0) &= \frac {f_0}{\rho_0}v_0.\end{align*}$$ Taking a step $\partial x$ in the $x$ direction doesn't change the direction of $v$, but only increases $\rho$, giving $$\begin{align*}
v_1 &= \langle \rho_0 + \partial x, 0, 0 \rangle \\
f_1 &= f(\rho_0 + \partial x)  \\
F(v_1) &= \frac {f_1}{\rho_0}v_0 \\
\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial x}  &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial \rho}.
\end{align*}$$

Now, instead of stepping in the $x$ direction, consider starting from $v_0$ and taking a step $\partial y$ in the $y$ direction: $$v_2 = \langle \rho_0, \partial y, 0 \rangle.$$  Since this step is orthogonal to $v_0$, $$\rho_2 = \rho_0 + \mathcal{O}([\partial y]^2)$$ and since $f$ depends only on $\rho$, we have to a first order approximation $$f_2 \approx f_0 \\
F(v_2) \approx \frac {f_0}{\rho_0}v_2$$ and, in the limit, $$\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial y}  = \frac f \rho.$$

By symmetry, $\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial z}  = \frac f \rho$ as well, giving $$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{div} F &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial \rho} + 2\frac f \rho \\
&= \frac 1 {\rho^2} \frac{d(\rho^2f(\rho))}{d \rho}
\end{align*}$$ as desired.

The above applies directly to points on the $x$ axis (other than the origin), and, by symmetry to any point in space (besides the origin).

Comment: I don’t remotely like writing $\partial x$ and $ \partial y$ for increments  $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$, and I find your notation somewhat confusing. But the heuristic calculation is good.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks Ted.  If by any chance you're able to post how a pro would write the solution, that would be of great service too.

Comment: I would plug into the general formula for divergence in coordinates.

Comment: @Mason Of course, the OP specifically said (see "Note") that he wanted NOT to do so.

Comment: @TedShifrin I meant to plug into the integration by parts formula for the divergence, which expresses the divergence in terms of the metric tensor. That would derive the expression for divergence in spherical coordinates.

Comment: @Mason Even more sophisticated yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, by your request, here's how I would present your heuristic argument.

It is important to observe that the divergence operator is rotationally invariant (see [this brief justification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761370/why-should-we-expect-the-divergence-operator-to-be-invariant-under-transformatio)). Since $F$ is invariant under rotation about the origin (being both rotationally symmetric in magnitude and radial), it follows that we can make the analysis at a single point and deduce that it holds at all points on the sphere of that radius.

So, as you did in the OP, let's consider $F=f(\rho)e_\rho$ at the point $a=(x,0,0)$ with $x>0$. Let's write $F=(M,N,P)$ for simplicity. Then $M(a)=f(x)$ and $N(a)=P(a)=0$.

Then varying $x$ is varying $\rho$ and keeping $\phi$ and $\theta$ fixed. It follows that
$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}(a) = \frac{\partial M}{\partial\rho}\Big|_{\rho=x,\phi=\theta=0} = f'(x).$$

Now, what about $\dfrac{\partial N}{\partial y}(a)$ and $\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial z}(a)$? As we move from the point $a$ varying $y$ (or $z$), instantaneously the point moves tangent to the sphere of radius $x$ centered at the origin, so instantaneously $\rho$ does not vary as we move in the $y$ direction. However, we must remember that we have $e_\rho =(x,y,z)/\rho$, so $N= f(\rho)\dfrac y\rho$.
At the point $a$, we have $\dfrac{\partial\rho}{\partial y} = \dfrac y\rho = 0$. It follows from the product rule and chain rule that
$$\frac{\partial N}{\partial y}(a) = f’(x)\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial y}\Big|_a + f(x)\cdot\frac1\rho\Big|_a + f(x)\cdot 0\cdot\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial y}\Big|_a = \frac{f(\rho)}{\rho}\Big|_{\rho=x}.$$ Similarly for $(\partial P/\partial z)(a)$.

We conclude that $\text{div}\,F(a) = \dfrac{\partial M}{\partial x}(a) + \dfrac{\partial N}{\partial y}(a) + \dfrac{\partial P}{\partial z}(a) =   f'(\rho) + 2\dfrac{f(\rho)}\rho$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you Ted, this is very helpful!